# What does it mean to erase an argument in an erased function?

Tags: idris

When I define type synonyms I typically erase them as `0 Foo : Type`. If there are parameters to that synonym, I can also erase those, like

```
0 Foo : (0 _ : Nat) -> (0 _ : Type) -> Type
```

but what does that mean? Since `Foo` doesn't exist at runtime, nothing it's passed needs to exist at runtime either. We can see this by defining a similar example without erased args

```
0 Foo' : Nat -> Type -> Type
```

and defining `Foo` in terms of `Foo'`

```
Foo x a = Foo' x a
```

which compiles fine. Is there any purpose to erasing arguments to erased functions?